Is it legal to use random images from the Internet in my personal study notes?
It's the images of objects, the images are helping learn new vocabulary. I don't know if they're under copyright. I mean if I get them from some website.
I want to use them only in my personal notes and don't share them with anyone.
Is it strictly legal, e.g. considered a fair use?

Unless there's a reason to believe otherwise, it is generally safe to assume that every picture, video, song, story, etc. is copyrighted. There's no paperwork involved in copyrighting your work; all you have to do is create it.

Of course, there's a big difference between violating someone's copyright and being punished for it. Copying the images for personal academic use may or may not be fair use, but it seems exceedingly unlikely anyone is going to know/care that you're doing it.
